# Struts Config error

Tags: java, apache, struts

Hello everyone I am trying to build the openclinic code from source. however I am stuck here because i cant seem to understand what is going on. The issue is that my `struts-config.xml` file is marked with the following error in eclipse

```
The content of element type "action-mappings" must match "(action)*".
```

Below is the complete `struts-config.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

 <!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_0.dtd">
<!--
 This is the Struts configuration file for the application,
 using the proposed new syntax.
-->
<struts-config>

  <!-- ========== Message Resources Definitions ============ -->

 <!-- ========== Form Bean Definitions =============== -->
 <form-beans>

 </form-beans>


<!-- ========== Global Forward Definitions ================ -->
<global-forwards>
  <forward name="login" path="/login.do"/>
 </global-forwards>


   <!-- ========== Action Mapping Definitions ============================== -->
  <action-mappings>
  <action path="/login"  type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.ShowAuthenticationPageAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/login.jsp"/>
  </action>

  <!-- check login -->
  <action path="/checkLogin"
        type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.ShowAuthenticationPageAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/checkLogin.jsp"/>
  </action>

  <!-- relogin -->
  <action path="/relogin"
        type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.ShowAuthenticationPageAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/sessionExpired.jsp"/>
  </action>

  <!-- logout -->
  <action path="/logout"
             type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.LogoutAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/loggedOut.jsp"/>
  </action>

  <action path="/changePassword" type="org.apache.struts.actions.ForwardAction" parameter="/userprofile/changepasswordonly.jsp"/>

   <!--===  <!-- Occupational Medicine - Risk Profile related actions   ===== -->

  <!-- Occupational Medicine - Show Risk Profile -->
  <action path="/healthrecord/showRiskProfile"
            type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.occupationalmedicine.ShowRiskProfileAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/main.do?Page=/healthrecord/showRiskProfile_view.jsp"/>
  </action>

  <!-- Occupational Medicine - Manage Periodic examinations Page -->
  <action    path="/healthrecord/managePeriodicExaminations"
             type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.occupationalmedicine.ManagePeriodicExaminationsAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/main.do?Page=curative/manageExaminations.jsp"/>
  </action>
   <!-- Occupational Medicine - Manage Alerts Page -->
  <action path="/healthrecord/manageAlertsPage"
             type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.occupationalmedicine.ManageAlertsPageAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/main.do?Page=/healthrecord/manageAlerts_view.jsp"/>
  </action>

        <!-- Health Record - Actions ===== -->
  <action path="/healthrecord/managePrintHistoryPopup"
             type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.occupationalmedicine.ManagePrintHistoryAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/healthrecord/printHistoryPopup.jsp"/>
  </action>
  <!-- Health Record - Save Lab Analyses Action -->
  <action    path="/healthrecord/saveLabAnalyses"
      type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.healthrecord.SaveLabAnalysesAction">
    <forward name="examinationsOverview" path="/main.do?Page=/curative/manageExaminations.jsp"/>
  </action>

  <!-- Health Record - Create Transaction -->
  <action path="/healthrecord/createTransaction"
             type="be.mxs.webapp.wl.struts.actions.healthrecord.CreateTransactionAction">
  </action>
   <!-- Health Record - Edit Transaction -->
  <action path="/healthrecord/editTransaction"
       type="be.mxs.webapp.wl.struts.actions.healthrecord.EditTransactionAction">
  </action>

   <!-- Health Record - Update Transaction -->
  <action path="/healthrecord/updateTransaction"
             type="be.mxs.webapp.wl.struts.actions.healthrecord.UpdateTransactionAction">
  </action>
  <!-- Health Record - Delete Transaction -->
  <action path="/healthrecord/manageDeleteTransaction"
             type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.healthrecord.ManageDeleteTransactionAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/main.do?Page=curative/index.jsp"/>
  </action>

   <!--Health Record - manage Vaccination -->
  <action path="/healthrecord/manageVaccination"
             type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.healthrecord.ManageVaccinationAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/main.do?Page=/healthrecord/manageVaccination_view.jsp"/>
  </action>
  <!-- Health Record - manage Next Vaccination -->
  <action path="/healthrecord/manageNextVaccination"
             type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.healthrecord.ManageNextVaccinationAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/main.do?Page=/healthrecord/manageVaccination_view.jsp"/>
  </action>

  <!-- Health Record - show Vaccination summary -->
  <action path="/healthrecord/showVaccinationSummary"
             type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.healthrecord.ShowVaccinationSummaryAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/main.do?Page=/healthrecord/vaccinationsSummary_view.jsp"/>
  </action>
  <!-- Health Record - show Vaccination history -->
  <action path="/healthrecord/showVaccinationHistory"
             type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.healthrecord.ManageNextVaccinationAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/main.do?Page=/healthrecord/vaccinationHistory_view.jsp"/>
  </action>
  <!-- Health Record - manage Clinical Contact -->
  <action path="/healthrecord/manageClinicalExamination"
             type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.healthrecord.ManageClinicalExaminationAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/main.do?Page=/healthrecord/manageClinicalExamination_view.jsp"/>
  </action>

        <!-- Health Record - Absent -->
  <action path="/healthrecord/showPeriodicExaminations"
      type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.occupationalmedicine.ShowPeriodicExaminationsAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/healthrecord/managePeriodicExaminations.do"/>
  </action>
  <action path="/main"
          type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.ShowAuthenticationPageAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/main.jsp"/>
  </action>
  <action path="/patientdata"
            type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.ShowAuthenticationPageAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/main.do?Page=_common/patient/patientdata.jsp"/>
  </action>
  <action path="/patientedit"
         type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.ShowAuthenticationPageAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/main.do?Page=_common/patient/patientedit.jsp"/>
  </action>
  <action path="/patienthistory"
        type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.ShowAuthenticationPageAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/main.do?Page=_common/patient/patienthistory.jsp"/>
  </action>
  <action path="/patientnew"
      type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.ShowAuthenticationPageAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/main.do?Page=_common/patient/patientedit.jsp"/>
  </action>
  <action path="/patientslist"
       type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.ShowAuthenticationPageAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/main.do?Page=_common/patientslist.jsp"/>
  </action>
  <action path="/print"
            type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.ShowAuthenticationPageAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/_common/print/print.jsp"/>
  </action>
  <action path="/start"
        type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.ShowAuthenticationPageAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/main.do?Page=_common/start.jsp"/>
  </action>
  <action path="/managePeriodicExaminations"
      type="be.dpms.medwan.webapp.wl.struts.actions.ShowAuthenticationPageAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/main.do?Page=curative/manageExaminations.jsp"/>
  </action>
</action-mappings>
</struts-config>
```

Comment: Please try to read the help section of stackoverflow before post any code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest XML comments as you've done here:

```
<!--===  <!-- Occupational Medicine - Risk Profile related actions   ===== -->
```

Remove that and it's a valid document.